# Do-While loop on user input - check if input is not empty or int (java)

Tags: java

I want the user to be repeatedly asked a question if the user input is either empty OR not an int. This is what I have so far:

```
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter id: ");
            int id = scn.nextInt();
         } while (!scn.hasNextInt());
```

Answer (score 1):

How about simply :

```
while (scanner.hasNextInt());
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem asked? Give the asker (or the next person to come along) some context about what your code does vs what the question's code does.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

boolean running = true;

```
while(running){
    String s = scn.nextLine();
    if(!(s!=""||isInt(s))){
        running = false;
    }
}
```

You need to implement your own isInt() function, but some google will give you this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this removing `!`:

```
while (scn.hasNextInt());
```

Comment: What about emptiness?